# finding the factors of a function via gcd

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a function say, $f(x)$, why is it true that if the GCD of the polynomial and its derivative,$f'(x)$, has a common divisor $\geq 1$, then we have a divisor of the polynomial?

Comment: Isn't it true regardless of $f'(x)$, i.e., for any polynomial $g(x)$ in general, and not just $f'(x)$ in specific?

Comment: yeah it is. I was just wondering why it's usually taught with a $f(x)$ and it's derivative. But I guess the only reason is convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if $\,\gcd(f,g)\,$ is nontrivial, then it is a nontrivial divisor of $\,f.\,$ One examines the special case $\,\gcd(f,f')\,$ when one seeks to test if $\,f\,$ has factors of multiplicity $\,n> 1,\,$ since if $\,f = g^n h\,$ then $\,f' = g^{n-1}(ng'h+gh')\,$ so $\,g^{n-1}\,$ is a nontrivial common divisor of $\,f,f'.$

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $f(x)$ and [something else] have a GCD with positive degree, by definition, the GCD is a divisor of $f(x)$. Did you mean something about multiple roots?

Comment: I just wanted to know why does this work for the derivative and the function? What's so special about the derivative

Comment: There isn't. In theory, you could try taking GCDs of $f$ and any other polynomial. It's not likely you'll find a factor with either method though. What you might be thinking of is: if $f$ and its derivative have a non-trivial GCD, then $f$ has a multiple root.